# 'export' command not found on new terminal window

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

Upon opening a new terminal I will get

```
-bash: ‘export: command not found
```

This line will only appear once then my base cmd line reappears.

I have read the other stackoverflow answers that seem similar but for some reason they get the error

```
-bash: ‘export: command not found
```

multiple times consecutively rather than just once.

I want to understand why this is appearing and if so what are likely causes. I am currently working on creating a website and had installed some of the requisite things like ruby but I do not know what specifically would have caused this.

Comment: The single curly quote in your error message is suspicious. I would inspect all your dot file (`.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc) and search for a case where `export VAR=value` is enclosed in curly single quotes. These might have come from cutting and pasting from a web page, for example, accidentally including the quotes.

Comment: BTW, our sister site [unix.se] is generally a better fit for general-purpose diagnosis of UNIX error messages; Stack Overflow is specific to questions about problems *unique to software development* (note the **and** connecting that entry in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to the other conditions, whereas most are connected by a more-permissive "or").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message shows a U+2018 character (*"LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK"*), i.e. a "smart quote".

This is likely coming from a `.bashrc` or `.profile` that's executed on Bash startup. Look for it next to an utterance of `export`.

Since it's not a script character (like a normal quote `'`) Bash is considering it to be part of the command name, and there is indeed no such command as `‘export`.